# How to change the markup created by menu item only on chosen items?

Tags: menus, admin, html

How to add a checkbox to the menu item in WordPress backend that says "Make this a Mega Menu Container"? In my mind it should look something like this (Photoshop draft): 
[image]

And when the box is checked instead of adding another standard ul > li DOM element a div container is added instead?

I have no idea how to approach this. I was planning to use walker to change the DOM for the menu, but how to "activate" the walker only for some menus - in this case the menus that I choose by that checkbox to be the mega menu?

Comment: So your first question is how to identify specific menu, which depends on how do you imagine this bit of custom data will be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this one is solved. I actually created a separate items that can be dragged in as a link, but are actually hard coded pieces of markup with adequate classes.